# How to split string after second hyphen

Tags: angular, typescript, split

I am creating users through an API and pre-append with Id from another API and then save it. when fetching the names on the front end, it should only display names without pre-appended Id.

Example 1:
S20000-KDW255258-User1-User2-User3

**Expected results:** User1-User2-User3

Example 2:
RTW000-RWSTY3500-Testing-Testing-Testing-User

**Expected results:** Testing-Testing-Testing-User

What I have tried without getting the desired results:

```
getUserName(userName: string) {

    // const userNameWithoutId = userName.split('-').slice(2).join('-');
    // return userNameWithoutId;

    const newName = userName.match("/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1]")
    console.log("New name: " + newName);
    return newName;
}
```

How can I split and get everything after the second hyphen?

Comment: What should be the return value when there is no match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Nothing, i just need to display anything after pre-appended Id

Comment: You can write the pattern using a capture group `/^(?:[^-\s]*-){2}(.+)/` and check if the group exists first. If the group does not exists, then you could return an empty string. See https://regex101.com/r/d6OK8V/1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by different ways. One is to use regex:

```
string.match(/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1]
```

```js
function getUserName(userName) {
  return userName.match(/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1]
}

console.log(getUserName('S20000-KDW255258-User1-User2-User3'))
console.log(getUserName('RTW000-RWSTY3500-Testing-Testing-Testing-User'))
console.log(getUserName('Testing-Testing-Testing-User'))
```

Comment: I have moved it to a function and i am not getting the desired results. Please correct me if i am using the regex in a correct way.

Comment: It's not `.match("/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1]")` but `.match(/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1])`

Comment: var newName = userName.match(/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1])
It is complaining looking for ';' and when it still complains after adding it

Comment: I have done an update.

Comment: Is the function in javascript or typescript? I have changed to return userName.match(/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)[1]
and now it just failed as UI it get broken and i can't see the error

Comment: Then use `userName.match(/^.*?-.*?-(.*)$/)![1]`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that the `slice` operator does not modify the original array.

rather it returns a shallow copy. see MDN docs -> [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

meaning that when the statement `userName.split('-').slice(2).join('-');`  does not modify the userName variable.

so when you try to get the secondInDex, you are still operating against the original value.

change your code to

```
const userNameWithoutId = userName.split('-').slice(2).join('-');
```

then modify your logic to work against the user name that has been cleansed. i.e.

Comment: I am not getting desired results, please have a look on the function that i have created